# Maneras de llamar Metodos de funciones Jquery

Tags: jquery

**Cuales son las maneras adecuadas para llamar funciones**
*Es obligatorio llamar a document ??, para realizar las llamadas*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:abrir_cerrar_reg();"><h5>Registro</h5></a>
```

Comment: Cuales son las maneras mas practicas de llanar funciones de jquery y si es necesario poner $(document).ready a cada funcion o archivos que contengan codigo jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El metodo **.ready** te ofrece una forma segura de ejecutar codigo JavaScript tan pronto sea la pagina DOM (Document Object Model) segura de Manipular, ya que de lo contrario no pudiera ser manipulada de forma segura (Tu Script pudiera estar haciendo referencia a código de tu pagina que aun no este "cargado") hasta que el documento este "listo".

Ahora, la forma en que ***JQUERY*** detecta este estado de preparacion para el desarrollador es a traves de **$( document ).ready()**, haciendo uso de tu mismo ejemplo:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").click(function() {
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="javascript:abrir_cerrar_reg();">
    <h5>Registro</h5>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Otra manera de hacer el llamado del evento, muy común entre desarrolladores experimentados es usar la tipografía **$()** para **$( document ).ready()**. Si deseas escribir código para que las personas que no tienen experiencia puedan entender, es mejor usar la forma larga, para tu mismo ejemplo seria:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('.llamada').click(function() {
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="" class="llamada">
    <h5>Registro</h5>
  </a>
  <!--Puedes llamar al evento instanciando la clase-->
</body>

</html>
```

De esta manera no estarías obligado a escribir **$( document ).ready()**. También se puede pasar una función en una llamada a $( document ).ready() en lugar de pasar a una función anónima.

```
// Pasando un nombre de función en ves de una función anónima.

function readyFn( jQuery ) {
    // Codigo que se ejecutara cuando el documento este listo
}

$( document ).ready( readyFn );
// o:
$( window ).on( "load", readyFn ); //También puedes hacer uso de esta manera.
```

Lee la documentación [Aqui](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). Saludos

Comment: gracias amigo voy a analizarlo y estudiarlo

Comment: por cierto inicie una pregunta de como eliminar variables de la url con jquery, si puedes para que me ayudes porfa